# Standard HTML layout for image slider

Tags: html

While writing my website using HTML5 standard, I come across image slider for which I didn't find relative tag. I did research and find out div="slider" is mostly used for slider. But also, HTML5 is about completely eliminating div and span like tag for specific tags. For this, I am using section tag. Which one is the best practice?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<body class="body">
    <header class="mainHeader">
        <figure id="logo">
            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo">
        </figure> 
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html" style="color: #EE2B32;">Home</a>     </li>
                <li><a href="courses.html">Courses</a></li>
                <li><a href="lectures.html">Lectures</a></li>
                <li><a href="admission.html">Admission</a></li>
                <li><a href="facilities.html">Facilities</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main class="home">
        <section class="slider">
            <ul>
                <li> <img src="images/slider/1.jpg" alt="Graduation Day"> </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
        <section class="mainContent">
            <h3>Introduction</h3>
            <p class="para">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. </p>
        </section>
    </main>
    <footer class="mainFooter">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home |</a></li>
            <li><a href="courses.html">Courses |</a></li>
            <li><a href="lectures.html">Lectures |</a></li>
            <li><a href="admission.html">Admission |</a></li>
            <li><a href="facilities.html">Facilities |</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://islingtoncollege.edu.np">&copy; Islington College</a></li>
        </ul>    
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess `div` tags should be the best option followed by section tags but it actually depends on the usage. For the image slider, I guess section tags should be best. If you have any queries with HTML5 coding, I think (http://w3schools.com) is the place to visit.